# How to create local.properties for android project in jenkins?

Tags: android, jenkins, build, continuous-integration, gradlew

We have an android project for an application, it builds without any error on our local machines. Recently had to configure jenkins for the same.

Every time we run the job the `BUILD FAILED`. Looking for the solution to the error we got to know that the `local.properties` is missing in the jenkins jobs workspace of our project.

Usually this file is created locally by Android Studio. Is there any way to get this done using gradle commands or code changes?
For our jenkins `sdk.dir = "/var/lib/jenkins/tools/android-sdk"`

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*A simple hack* - Try echoing the path to a file using shell at the same job before using any `gradle` command as :-

```
echo "<path to the sdk on jenkins" >> local.properties
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to install a plugin to create this configuration file. For example, you can use this: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Config+File+Provider+Plugin. 
But the main problem is that your `local.properties` file will be in another folder, so your gradlew execution won't be able to find it.

Another solution is to setup your Jenkins System configuration, adding an **environment variable** `ANDROID_HOME` and the value is `path\to\your\sdk`

Comment: this didn't help me sort out the problem